# HERE Isoline limitations?

Tags: here-api

Does the Isoline function have limitations?
For example if I do an isoline 200KMS from "Callington, SA" there are towns such as GALGA that are within 200KMS that are not highlighted.  I am using parameters 
'mode': 'fastest;truck;traffic:disabled'
'rangetype': 'distance'
A search on here we go for example will show that that is ~150kms away and with the 200kms specified.
I have tried changing the parameters to 'shortest;car;tracffic:disabled' but Galga was still excluded.

Another failure is that I can't do over 700kms from 12 Noble St, Kewdale WA 6105 without receiving a failure back through the javascript call.

I have tried making 'maxPoints' a higher value but it has made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first topic, this looks like an issue within the service. We will have a look for a solution and provide iit with one of the net releases.
To answer your second question, the current maximum is 500km for Isolines.